# injective morphism between line bundles on curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth projective, irreducible, curve, $\mathcal{L}$ be an invertible sheaf on $X$ and $\mathcal{L}' \subset \mathcal{L}$, an invertible subsheaf. Is $\deg(\mathcal{L}') \le \deg(\mathcal{L})$?

Comment: What is a subbundle of a line bundle?

Comment: Actually, are you talking about invertible sheaves? A sub bundle of a line bundle is either itself or the bundle of zero rank (which is just the base).

Comment: I have made the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Twist the inclusion by $\mathcal{L}^{-1}$, so that $\mathcal{L}^{-1} \otimes \mathcal{L}' \subset \mathcal{O}_X$, in particular it is an ideal sheaf (hence has non-positive degree).

Comment: Or twist the other way to find that $\mathcal{O}_X \subset \mathcal{L}'^{-1} \otimes \mathcal{L}$, so that the latter has a section, hence has nonnegative degree.