# Subbundles and image of vector bundle morphisms

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Motivated by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1370120/injective-morphism-between-line-bundles-on-curves) I want to clarify something regarding vector/line subbundles.

**Question 1** Suppose we have a morphism of vector bundles over a curve/Riemann surface $X$, $f : E \rightarrow F$. When is the image $\text{im}(f)$ a vector bundle? Is it always a subbundle of $F$?

I know that for kernels one needs to have constant rank (which let's assume is not included in the definition of vector bundle morphism for this post). Does something similar happens? I can intuitively see that wherever $x \in X$ $f$ vanishes, $\text{im}(f)$ will "*lose rank*", and I see that as undeserible for vector subbundles.

**Question 2** Is it true, as stated in the comment of the cited question, that the only subbundle of a line bundle is either itself or the zero bundle? I can see by some vanishing theorem that $H^0(X, L_2 \otimes L_1^*)$ vanishes whenever $\deg L_2 < \deg L_1$, but... I can see no further. Could there be line subbundles of a given one with less degree or does it follow from the injectivity that they must be isomorphic (when nonzero) just by purely linear-algebraic reasons $L_{1,x} \subset L_{2,x} \implies L_{1,x} = L_{2,x}~~\forall x \in X$?

I know these might seem extremely obvious, but I sincerely cannot wrap my head around these concepts when identifying vector bundles and the associated sheaves of local sections.

Comment: For question 2: let $E\subset L$ be a subbundle of a line bundle. It has a constant rank $r$ (its rank as a bundle) and for each point $x$, $E_x$ is a $r$ dimensional subspace of $L_x$. Since $L_x$ is one dimensional, either $E_x=\{0\}$ (when $r=0$) and $E$ is trivial, either $E_x=L_x$ (when $r=1$) and $E=L$.

Comment: For question 1: the image is always a coherent sheaf, so it is a subbundle if it has contant rank. That doesn't always happen: take $E = \mathbb C^2$ over $\mathbb C$ and consider $f : E \to E$ given by $f(z, (x, y)) =(z, z \cdot (x, y))$. Over $z \not= 0$ the image of $f$ is all of $E_z$, over $z = 0$ the image is $0$.

Comment: Thank you both, this solves my questions!